# Proof that the cartesian product of $n \in \mathbb{N}$ countably infinite sets is countably infinite - Induction

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Suppose we have $A_1, A_2, A_3, ..., A_n$ countably infinite sets. Their Cartesian product is countably infinite.

Proof by induction:

1. $n=1$

For n=1 the statement clearly holds.

2. Suppose that $A_1 \times A_2 \times ... \times A_k$ is countably infinite,
3. Prove that for $n=k+1$ the statement is true:

$A_1 \times A_2 \times ... \times A_k \times A_{k+1} = (A_1 \times A_2 \times ... \times A_k) \times A_{k+1} $

If we rewrite this in such a way so that we have a cartesian product of a set we know is countably infinite ($A_{k+1}$), and a cartesian product of sets we assumed is countably infinite (assumption in $2.$), does this mean that **if I show that a Cartesian product of two countably infinite sets is countably infinite, my statement holds**?

Note: I know that this has been asked (and answered before), but it was in a way I didn't understand. I need help in figuring out if my proof would be sufficient.

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: What precisely do you mean by $A\times B\times C$? Depending on the definition, the *equality* in 3. may be false.

Comment: It seems clear that by $A \times B \times C$ you mean $\{ (a,b,c): a\in A,\ b\in B, c\in C\}$. The point that @AndrésE.Caicedo is making (probably) is that the equality in 3 should not be interpreted as equality of sets, in which case it is false. However, the LHS and the RHS are isomorphic (there is a bijection between them) and thus they have the same cardinality, that is countably infinite.

Comment: @user Yes, but I would go further and add that even the "it seems clear" is not necessarily quite so, in that one then needs to ask what $(a,b,c)$ is, before one can conclude whether or not these things are equal or just equipotent. [The point being that whether "the proof is sufficient" or not depends on how these details are handled or glossed over.]

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I am basing what I wrote upon Kuratowski's definition of a pair, or more broadly a tuple. Based on Kuratowski:  $(a_1, a_2) = \{ \{ a_1 \}, \{a_1,a_2\} \} \} $. Analogically, we define $(a_1, a_2, ... , a_n) = ((a_1, a_2, ... , a_{n-1}), a_n)$.

Comment: Ah, very well. Yes, the argument is fine in that case.